# Problem when restart app on kiosk mode windows 10

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, kiosk-mode, windowsiot

We are developing a POS application which will be setup at our stores.
This app is an UWP application which run on Windows 10 IOT LTSC Kisk Mode and we decided to deploy by using side-loading.

In order to improve the update process, we have try using this library to implement the application update feature
https://github.com/Dwrandaz/AutoUpdateComponent

On desktop mode, It works well with out any problem. After update process, the application will be restarted and the new version will be loaded.
But on kiosk mode, sometimes after updated, the application can't restart:
- After update process, the application try to restart but it stuck on blue windows with loading spinner.
- We also try waiting for a few hours but nothing change
- If we try force restart device (use power off button) then after logged on kiosk mode, the application will be loaded with new version.
- We have been tested the update process for about 20 times and just 1 times this problem occurred.

Beside, this problem also occurred when we implement restart button using method `App.Current.Exit()` 
so we think that there is no problem with update process, it is problem of restart function when run on Kiosk mode.

If anyone know about this problem, please help us.

Comment: Have you monitored the system event log when the issue occurred?It seems that there is  some resource was not released when updating the app.

Comment: I have enabled log as recommendation of Microsoft but when error occurs , there is nothing

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT This is an issue being faced by a few folks across the web, we're seeing a very similar situation with no obvious explanation. Submitted a question over at [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114194/intune-kiosk-blue-screen-spinner-after-uwp-app-res.html)