# Manually update an windows app in kiosk mode doesn´t work

Tags: windows, uwp, kiosk-mode, appinstaller

Manually triggering update of an app when running windows in assigned access (Kiosk mode) doesn´t work.

I have read others facing the same issue and it feels like there is a bug in windows Kiosk mode. But maybe there is some reason for this behaviour?

I have an app that I sideload using an appinstaller file (my app consist of both a uwp part and a consol part linked with a bridge connection). The app works well in Kiosk mode besides the update part. If I enable automatic updates and link to a specific folder on my computer the automatic updates will work and update my app from the specific folder. However this way to update requires two restarts before it is automatically updated. I want to be able to manually trigger the update from within the app itself somehow and have it updated instantly.

I have tried to update using packagemanager using the function below. This works well in desktop but will always freeze in bluscreen with progressring if I run it in an account in Kiosk mode (assigned access).

```
PackageManager pm = new PackageManager();    
pm.AddPackageByAppInstallerFileAsync(new Uri("C:\\myLocalPath"), AddPackageByAppInstallerOptions.ForceTargetAppShutdown, pm.FindPackageVolume("C:\\"));
```

I have also tried to restart the app using the command below in order to trigger the automatic update without the need to restart the entire computer. This also works well in desktop but will freeze in bluscreen if I am in a Kiosk account.

```
AppRestartFailureReason result = await CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync("Restart");
```

Restarting the entire computer two times and enabling automatic updates will update the app without problems. Why is it not possible to use one of the methods above? Is this a bug in windows kiosk mode or is this really intended??

The same issue is also reported here:

[problem-when-restart-app-on-kiosk-mode-windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673943/problem-when-restart-app-on-kiosk-mode-windows-10)

and here:

[intune-kiosk-blue-screen-spinner-after-uwp-app-res](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114194/intune-kiosk-blue-screen-spinner-after-uwp-app-res.html)

Comment: Could you place the appx file in the app's local folder ?

Comment: Tried this but did not make it work. Actually I think my issue was that the account I use for assigned access first was created as a local account and then converted to an assigned access account. I really don´t understand why but this seems to not work!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to how I made this work here:
[The same problem described on microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114194/intune-kiosk-blue-screen-spinner-after-uwp-app-res.html?childToView=169987#answer-169987)

I don´t feel very confident with the whole assigned access and package installation concept. It works at the moment for me but my feeling is that it is not very stable. Many different ways of creating almost the same thing. The problem is that there are differences between the results depending on how you get there. For instance two assigne access accounts don´t behave the same if you created them differently. Also adding and removing both apps and accounts leaves trash that you don´t see but can cause problems.At least this is my feeling.